# Paypal Sandbox account not able to add digital goods feature

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am able to create sandbox accounts successfully on paypal but when i was able to add the product (digital goods), the sandbox site redirects to a live site. My question is how do i go about adding a product (digital goods) on the sandbox account.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you must be using some sort of class library/SDK to handle this for you and it's not redirecting correctly..??

You can do the redirect on your own.  It's simply a matter of calling SetExpressCheckout to get your token and setup the digital goods payment.  Then you just do the redirection on your own based on whether you're using the sandbox or the live server.  For the sandbox you'd redirect to:  https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/incontext?token=SECTOKEN

If you simply do that redirect on your own it should work just fine.  I've tested digital goods payments in the sandbox a lot in the past and have never had any issues with it.

Answer (score 0):

Add "sandbox." to the URL to sign up?

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_product-go&product=additional_payment&signup_profile=dg